# Is it possible to form design in Java like c#?

Tags: java, winforms, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm a new java app developer.
I've just installed swing plug-in and when I'm searching for swing tutorial there is just code to create forms and other components!
I want to know if it's possible to create forms as simple as we do it in c# with drag and drop?

Comment: Yes, but it's generally not recommended when you're trying to learn the API as you need to understand how layout managers work and how to apply them to complex interfaces

Comment: Which ide do you use?

Answer (score 4):

**Java Swing.**

It is possible with netbeans IDE which is having built-in Swing GUI Designer.
[Download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) from here.
Eclipse IDE is also having Swing GUI Designer Plugins.[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

**Java FX Scene Builder.**

Apart from Java SWING,Using Java FX also you can design UI using XML which can be used in Java Project.You have to learn about [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) and [Java FX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

try net beans or oracle's ADF -these provide drag and drop. there are many ide's